# Search results show highlighted text instead of title

Tags: search-results

I am using sharepoint 2013 foundation. When I search on some word for example "hellow world" I see 3 results. The first results show a highlighted column instead the title of the document. After this I see the some content of the document, and as last I see the path of my document.

I will see always the title as first meta data field in my search results. Can I configure this?

Comment: are these the office 2007 documents?

Comment: no, not only 2007. Also 2010 and 2013